# Is this proof of the convergence of a recurrence relation correct?

Tags: recurrence-relations

The relation:
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = a_n + e^{-a_n} (a_0 = 0)
\end{equation} 
Does it converge or diverge?

I've been working on this on and off for about a year, and I think I've figured out a proof:

Proof:

You can easily rewrite the relation as the following sum:
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = \sum_{m=0}^{n}e^{-a_m}
\end{equation} 
 Thus the question of convergence of divergence boils down to figuring out if the following series converges or diverges:
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}e^{-a_m}
\end{equation} 
Now Raabe's Test states for an arbitrary series:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}b_m
\end{equation} 
If:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}\right| = 1
\end{equation} 
And setting:
\begin{equation}
R = \lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\left|\frac{b_n}{b_{n+1}}\right|-1\right)
\end{equation} 
If $R > 1$, that series converges. If $R < 1$ that series diverges.

Now applying that test to my relation:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{e^{-a_n}}{e^{-a_{n+1}}}\right| &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{a_{n+1}}}{e^{a_{n}}}\\
 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{a_{n} + e^{-a_n}}}{e^{a_{n}}}\\
 &= \lim_{n\to\infty}e^{e^{-a_n}}\\
\end{align*} 
Assume $a_n$ diverges, i.e:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \infty
\end{equation} 
Since:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{-n}= 0
\end{equation} 
Thus:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{e^{-a_n}}= e^0 = 1
\end{equation} 
Thus it fulfills the first condition of Raabe's Test.
Now set $R$:
\begin{equation}
R =  \lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|-1\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(e^{e^{-a_n}}-1\right)
\end{equation} 
By a property of limits:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(e^{e^{-a_n}}-1\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}ne^{e^{-a_n}} - 1
\end{equation} 
And by the fact that the limit of a product is the product of the limits:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{e^{-a_n}} - 1 = \lim_{n\to\infty}n - 1
\end{equation} 
Which is a divergent limit i.e:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n - 1 = \infty
\end{equation} 
Therefore:
\begin{equation}
R > 1
\end{equation} 
Therefore the series converges. But since we assumed the series diverges, we have reached a contradiction and thus the series converges.

Is this proof correct?

Now please, I beg of you, could you please just point out the mistakes in my proof, and not solve the problem? This is a problem I work on when I'm bored or when I have free time to so pass time. So if my proof is incorrect, and you solve the problem, I'll have no problem to while my time away.

Comment: Your summation isn't correct. $a_1 = 1 + e^{-1}$, but your summation gives $a_1 = e^{-1}$.

Comment: fixed it by changing starting  point

Comment: The proof looks correct to me.

Now that you solved it, you can keep working on the problem to find a more elementary proof :)